# Libgdx how i create a 3D Low-Poly Terrain with chunks

Tags: java, 3d, libgdx, terrain

dear stackoverflow community,

**I have now idea, how i can create a Low-Poly 3d Terrain in Libgdx,**

By googling i found remains from the libgdx blog or website they can't help me, but by the research nothing what can help me.

I create a Value Noise but it does not work and i think its not the right way to do it.

Do you know a good tutorial or websites? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LibGDX is not a game engine so don't expect any "generateTerrain()" method. You need to implement it yourself.

[Here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/3D-Graphics) you can find general information about how to use libGDX for 3D.

And [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/HeightMapTest.java) you can find actual code that creates a height map.